How do I use custom Postgres types with Python's Pydantic+SQLModel+SQLAlchemy stack?
I have this custom type in Postgres:
create type triple_lang as (en text, fr text, es text);

In python it is represented with SQLModel class
class TripleLang(SQLModel, table=False):
    en: Optional[str] = None
    ru: Optional[str] = None
    uk: Optional[str] = None

    class Config:
        from_attributes = True

In table models it is used via the sqlalchemy_utils library's CompositeType class. Normally, it looks something like this:
from datetime import datetime, date
from typing import Optional

from pydantic import ConfigDict
from sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql import JSONB, ARRAY
from sqlalchemy_utils import CompositeType
from sqlmodel import Field, SQLModel, Text, Column, select

from my_awesomest_module import TripleLang

Class DataExtended(SQLModel, table=True):
    __table_args__ = {"schema": "public"}
    __tablename__ = "data_extended"
    model_config = ConfigDict(from_attributes=True, arbitrary_types_allowed=True)

    id: Optional[int] = Field(default=None)
    title: TripleLang = Field(primary_key=True, sa_type=CompositeType(name="triple_lang", columns=[Column("en", Text), Column("fr", Text), Column("es", Text)]))
    description: TripleLang = Field(primary_key=True, sa_type=CompositeType(name="triple_lang", columns=[Column("en", Text), Column("fr", Text), Column("es", Text)]))
    some_other_data: Optional[list[str]] = Field(default=None, sa_type=ARRAY(Text))
    some_date: Optional[date] = None

Finally, in the scripts, when creating a DB engine, I have to use psycopg2 as driver (as far as I know, newer psycopg doesn't support custom types yet), and call register_composites method whenever I create a connection, like so:
from sqlalchemy_utils import register_composites

db_client = DBClient(connection_params=db_config, driver="psycopg2")  # assume this creates a proper DB engine

with db_client.get_session() as session:
    register_composites(session.connection())
    ## ... interact with the db ....

This is all nice and dandy, except for that the object I get as a result is not 100% what I expect, and I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.
Assuming the above class, I would expect this:
data_obj = DataExtended(
               id=1,
               title={"en": "potato", "fr": "pomme de terre", "es": "papa"}
               description={"en": "earth fruit", "fr": "fruit de la terre", "es": "fruta de la tierra"}
               some_other_data=["plop", "func"]
               some_date="Oct 11, 2021")

However, I'm getting this:
data_obj = DataExtended(
               id=1,
               title=["potato", "pomme de terre", "papa"]
               description=["earth fruit", "fruit de la terre", "fruta de la tierra"]
               some_other_data=["plop", "func"]
               some_date="Oct 11, 2021")

I admit, this is not all that big of an issue, since I get my data, and can work around different format, but it so bugs me that I can't figure it out.
Please, advise.
